# It is possible to extract hyperlink from google sheet using php?

Tags: php, csv

I have a spreadsheet and its cells that include hyperlinks:
[google sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEcHC.png)

I want to get links using php

```
$sheet_link =   "file.csv";
$handle = fopen($sheet_link, "r");
$keys = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
if (($handle = fopen($sheet_link, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       $spreadsheet_data1[] = array_combine($keys, $data);
       echo "<pre>";
       echo print_r($spreadsheet_data1);
       echo "</pre>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
else
   die("Problem reading csv");
```

its return simple text string not hyperlink.

[CSV view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMJxk.jpg)

Comment: It seems you've downloaded the sheet as a CSV. Does the raw CSV file contain the link information? (You can check it using any text editor.)

Comment: Yes, I added link.
I'm attached screenshot link in the question which I want and above code return only text information but not return the hyperlink. @ADyson

Comment: That's not a screenshot of your CSV file though is it. Or at least, not as viewed through a text editor (e.g. Notepad).

Comment: I added screenshot in the question you can check as well.

Comment: No. Show it as seen **in a text editor**. CSV is a **text file**. I thought I made my request fairly clear, but apparently not.

Comment: Also, please show the exact output you are seeing in your PHP for that code, so we have a comparison.

Comment: attach your csv file sample.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRz-OAKD051I3CXGsHIuHZQ6yIwSnEs_5C3mHxKJXDFCWs1aTms7plq3lzFz-ni0iGzHb7aqzPhNgpv/pub?output=csv

Comment: @ADyson here is the output. 

https://ibb.co/6gTvkn0

Comment: When viewed in Notepad (as I asked you to do originally!) your file contains `column1,column2,column3,column4,column5
item1,attribute1,attribute1,attribute1,attribute1
item2,attribute2,attribute2,attribute2,attribute2
item3,attribute3,attribute3,attribute3,attribute3
item4,attribute4,attribute4,attribute4,attribute4
item5,attribute5,attribute5,attribute5,attribute5`. Just plain text. So there's nothing wrong with your PHP code. You need to find a different way to export from google sheets which preserves the data you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson can you please let me know is there any other way to how to do that ? :)

Comment: I don't know anything about google sheets sorry, but I'm sure you can research the export options available. Perhaps it can be exported to Excel format, for example, and maybe that would preserve it. There are ways that PHP can read an Excel XLSX file, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

When you save a file as .csv it will only save the linktext, not the link (in your case attribute1). You can see this when you open it in the text editor.

You will have to save the spreadsheet in any other format to extract the link.

Comment: here is the link of spreadsheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRz-OAKD051I3CXGsHIuHZQ6yIwSnEs_5C3mHxKJXDFCWs1aTms7plq3lzFz-ni0iGzHb7aqzPhNgpv/pub?output=csv

Comment: Like I said, open the sheet in any editor and you will find that the hyperlink is not there, only the linktext. (attribute1) You need to save your spreadsheet in another format. Try saving as .txt or .xlsx and extracting the link from there.